# How to adapt this VBA Function to Google sheets

Tags: vba, excel, google-sheets

At work we use this Excel VBA Function a lot:

```
Sub Find_Matches()
    Dim CompareRange As Variant, x As Variant, y As Variant
    ' Set CompareRange equal to the range to which you will
    ' compare the selection.
    Set CompareRange = Range("H2:H9")
    ' NOTE: If the compare range is located on another workbook
    ' or worksheet, use the following syntax.
    ' Set CompareRange = Workbooks("Book2"). _
    '   Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C1:C5")
    '
    ' Loop through each cell in the selection and compare it to
    ' each cell in CompareRange.
    For Each x In Selection
        For Each y In CompareRange
            If x = y Then x.Offset(0, 3) = x
        Next y
    Next x
End Sub
```

And it's really helpfull for us because of the offset function. as we can adapt it to compare, for example, Names and Birth dates from a selection, with another selection, mark with a "x" the results that match, then compare if both the name and birth date match to confirm that its the same person.

it in the end looks something like this, but with thousands of data in "To compare" and "Database":

(the above function was adapted for the example below, to search in the H for the names I select with the mouse in A, then I use another with compare range changed for the birth date and then a IF function in column F to see if there's a "x" in D and E, if yes it displays "yes")

[image: Function results looks like this]

But I don't know how to use the google scripts, and only one computer at the office has excel, it would be amazing productive for us if we could convert the Function into google and use it on other computers that don't have access to excel and VBA.

So, there is a equivalent script to do this function in google sheets?

Comment: possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20803155/any-way-to-use-vba-on-google-spreadsheet

Comment: I think not, i saw this post you linked when searching for solutions but it don't do the same thing that i need on my macro.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code translation site.  What have you tried?  Show us your attempt to translate the code above.

Comment: I don't see why you don't do it with formulas rather than with programming (valid for both Excel and GSheet). However, if you want to go with Apps-Script, i fear you have to learn the scripting language. It has a similar concepts of Workbooks and Worksheets and Ranges, but the syntax is different (it bases on JavaScript), so no easy 1:1 translation.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write a macro to achieve this result. Checking for an existence of a value from a range in another range can be achieved using the built-in MATCH function. Here is an example demonstrating how to do it:

[image]

In your specific case that would be the formula to put in e.g. cell D3

```
=arrayformula(if(not(isna(match(A3:A9; H3:H9; 0))); "x"; ""))
```